# Replace white spaces to &nbsp;

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I want to replace all whitespaces to `&nbsp;`

```
<div class="red-c"><p>Hel  lo <span style="background-color: rgb(204, 193, 217);">h   el  lo</span> <span style="font-size: 18px;">h<span style="background-color: rgb(127, 127, 127);">e  ll</span>o</span> h   ello
</p></div>
```

with the result

```
<div class="red-c"><p>Hel&nbsp;&nbsp;lo&nbsp;<span style="background-color: rgb(204, 193, 217);">h&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;el&nbsp;&nbsp;lo</span>&nbsp;<span style="font-size: 18px;">h<span style="background-color: rgb(127, 127, 127);">e&nbsp;&nbsp;ll</span>o</span>&nbsp;h&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ello
</p></div>
```

I have not found a solution for this here in stackoverflow.

Comment: How are you rendering this HTML?

Comment: I'll help you out friend, here you go, lots of no-breaking-spaces -> **http://jsfiddle.net/9dt1n9ef/1/**

Comment: if your goal is simply to preserve whitespace, then you dont need `&nbsp;` , there is a `css` attribute `white-space:pre;`  that you can utilize.   `.red-c{white-space:pre;}`

Comment: I have tried that also, but here the line spacing (<br /> are too large

https://jsfiddle.net/r8L15arj/1/

Comment: Then fix the line spacing with `line-spacing`, for example.

Comment: @MarcoLeifert You have misstated your problem. It is not that you "want to replace all whitespaces to `&nbsp;`". It is rather that you want "whitespace not to be collapsed".

Answer (score -1):

You may use pure JavaScript solution like the following:

```
function replaceWs(txt){
    out = '';
    for (i = 0; i < txt.length; i++){
      if (txt[i] == ' '){
        out += '&nbsp;';
      }
      else{
        out += txt[i];
      }          
    }
    return out;
  }
```

Checkout [**this demo**](http://jsbin.com/xozabovede/edit?output)

Comment: thanks but this solutions replaces also the whitespace within the span tags

Comment: Pass whatever text nodes to the function to do the task.